# Custom metadata information in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to create custom metadata information in the entities? Something that would use the already present functionality of using either Annotation, yml or xml to store metadata about the entity.

Example:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
 * @CUSTOM\Meta(key="value")               // <-- Extra information
 */
protected $text;
```

For what I've been researching, it seems that I should use the functionality of ClassMetadataFactory. Is it possible, or would I have to make it from scratch?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: The purpose is an expansion of the doctrine:generate:crud command. With this I could inform the command, for example, what time of FormType it should use to build the entity form.